# Interesting identity about Trig Functions and Complex Numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, induction

I recently discovered the beautiful identity
$$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$$
and I proved it using induction. However, I can't figure out if this identity also applies to non-integer values of $n$. How can I determine this, and how do I prove it? Certainly not with induction...

**NOTE:** If I could prove the original identity *without* induction, then that should do it... but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: [Depends on how you define $z^n$ for non-integer $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: $\cos\theta + i\sin\theta = e^{i\theta}$, so yes, it works for all $n \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: see alos here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

Comment: @tilper you are probably assuming $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}~\dots$

Comment: @DrSonnhardGraubner see my first comment.

Comment: @tilper You claim it holds for any $n\in\mathbb R$, but if I take $n=1/2$ and $\theta=2\pi$, the result is: $$1^{1/2}=-1$$ So you are missing a few things here.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, fixed statement:  It works${}^†$ for all $n \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identity *almost* holds for any $n\in\mathbb C$, but only under appropriate definitions and appropriate values of $\theta$.  Take $n=1/2$ and $\theta=2\pi$, for example, and you will get

$$1^{1/2}\stackrel?=-1$$

Which usually isn't taken to be true.  Of course, you could argue that $1^{1/2}=-1$ and $4^{1/2}=-2$, but then for $n=1/2$ and $\theta=0$, you will get

$$1^{1/2}\stackrel?=1$$

Surely, we have

$$(\cos(0)+i\sin(0))^{1/2}=(\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi))^{1/2}$$

Indeed, this must surely be true regardless of our definition of $x^{1/2}$, but it most certainly cannot be the case that these expressions are both positive one and negative one simultaneously:

$$\cos(0/2)+i\sin(0/2)\ne\cos(2\pi/2)+i\sin(2\pi/2)$$

If you did decide they were, then expressions such as $1^\pi$ would become extraordinarily vague and very much misleading.

---

So when does this hold?  Well, it depends on your definition of exponentiation at non-integer values.  For the most part, we generally define exponentiation as follows:

$$x^n=e^{x\ln(n)}$$

But $\ln(n)$ is quite vague (since $e^t=e^{t+2\pi i}$), which is why we have [principal logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value),
 using the [$\operatorname{atan2}$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2):

$$\operatorname{Log}(z)=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{atan2}(\Im(z),\Re(z))$$

Under this definition, we have

$$(\cos(0)+i\sin(0))^{1/2}=\cos(0/2)+i\sin(0/2)$$

But,

$$(\cos(2\pi/2)+i\sin(2\pi/2))^{1/2}\ne\cos(2\pi/2)+i\sin(2\pi/2)$$

More generally, for any $n\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Z$, the identity holds for $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$ and fails everywhere else.  For $n\in\mathbb Z$, the identity holds for all $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for another beautifully explanation! :)

Comment: @Nilknarf Ofc, this problem only arises for $n\notin\mathbb Z$.  For $n\in\mathbb Z$, everything looks dandy.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
$$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin\theta$$

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, the power works for $n$ as integers, but we do need to be careful for non-integer $n$ as $\log$ function could has lots of branches for complex parameter. This post has a good explanation:  [Complex power of complex number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325545/complex-power-of-complex-number).