# Complex numbers and quadratic

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $\alpha,\beta$ are roots of $t^2-2t+5=0,(a+1)/2=\cot\phi$ then show
> $$((a+\alpha)^n-(a+\beta)^n)/(\alpha-\beta)=
> 2^{n-1}\operatorname{cosec}^n(\phi)\sin(n\phi)$$

My try was to put values of sum, difference and $a$.
I got
$$2^n\operatorname{cosec}^n(\phi)(\cos(n\phi) \pm i\sin (n\phi)-\sin^n(\phi))/(\pm4i)$$
I can't go any further, can anyone help please?
I found $\alpha,\beta$ and $a$ from the relation substituted it and used De Moivre

Comment: You have been around for seven months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: I'm afraid I downvoted this post for the reason that José describes. If you edit your post, then please let me know, and I will remove the downvote. You should also include more detail about what you have tried.

Comment: I am trying but unable to understand math jax.i have tried to edit sorry for breaking rules

Comment: Thanks a lot , thank i ll learn mathjax straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$t=1\pm2i$$

WLOG $\alpha=1+2i,\beta=?\implies\alpha-\beta=?$

$$a+\alpha=2\cot\phi-1+1+2i=\dfrac{2(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)}{\sin\phi}$$

Using [Review of a proof for De Moivre's theorem using mathematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420291/review-of-a-proof-for-de-moivres-theorem-using-mathematical-induction) to find $$(a+\alpha)^n$$

Similarly find $$(a+\beta)^n$$

Comment: (b+α)  should actually be (a+β).

Comment: @Guji2203, Thanks